# Toolbars in ToolStripContainer don't keep their position

Tags: c#, .net, forms, toolbar, toolstrip

I don't know why this is happening... But, every time I open the designer for a form, the toolbars in the ToolStripContainer move one under the other, instead of being all on the same line (how I left it before).

Is there any fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Visual Studio, by default, adds the Layout Toolbar to the ToolStripContainer.

Visual Studio keeps seperate layouts of the ToolStripContainer for different types of editors. It makes sense since for example, when you are editing a form in the form designer you do not need the Text Editor toolbar. Similarly a Dialog editor toolbar is unnecessary when the text editor is opened. For example, you may try to open an xml file and by default, the Xml Editor Toolbar is added to the container.

Any arrangement made to the container is kept, but seperately. You can manually open close toolbar items to arrange the container however you like.